# Changing a Routes Key ID, from /threads/ID to /threads/uuid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a threads model, that has Thread (id, uuid, title...)

Here is the path:

When the controller redirects: http://localhost:3000/threads/828b9a2ffc

In the logs I then see:

```
Started GET "/threads/828b9a2ffc" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Jul 09 17:24:02 -0700 2011
  Processing by ThreadsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"828b9a2ffc"}
```

The issue here is I don't want 828b9a2ffc to be the ID, I want it to interpruted as uuid in the parameters, so I should see:

```
  Parameters: {"uuid"=>"828b9a2ffc"}
```

How can that be made possible in the routes file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious but what's wrong with using a route like:

```
match '/threads/:uuid' => 'threads#show', :via => :get
```

in your `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be:

```
match 'threads/:uuid' => 'threads#show', :as => :thread
```

That will make the last part of the url available as `params[:uuid]`.  If you already have

```
resources :threads
```

defined then just put it above that in your routes file and it will override the `threads#show` path already defined.

Answer (score 0):

In routes.rb you need something like this:

```
get 'threads/:uuid', :action => "show", :as => "by_uuid"
```

This will create a `thread_by_uuid_path(thread_object)` helper method but if you also have:

```
resources :threads
```

... there will still be the standard `show` route which uses `:id` and will conflict with the new one you define above.  You could define each of the routes manually and deleted the `resources :threads` line, but I would tend to leave the route alone and change the controller method like this:

```
def show
  @thread = Thread.find_by_uuid(params[:id]) || Thread.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

... this way the ID can still be used even though you expect the UUID to be passed.